# Why do we wave the Lulav / etrog?

Tags: sources-mekorot, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, sukkot, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

The mitzvah mentioned in the Torah just says to "take" 4 species. The Torah doesn't mention anything about waving them. The Talmud mentions waving them at certain points in Hallel, but there doesn't appear to be a mention of waving them at the brachah. (Thanks, robev). What is the purpose for waving them at all?

Note - this is not the same as [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47378/5275) which asks why it's done at the specific Hallel verses.

Comment: This is dealt with on P. 284 of the Artscroll Machzor for Sukkot and on Sukkah 37b and 38a.

Comment: Waving at the Berakha is for people who aren't saying Hallel then. (In Europe that used to be how 99% of Jews did it.)

Answer (score 5):

**Waving the lulav represents our victorious emergence from the judgment of [Rosh Hashanah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosh_Hashanah)/[Yom Kippur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yom_Kippur).**

---

The following [Midrash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midrash) appears in [Midrash Tanchuma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanhuma) on [Parshat Emor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emor) # 18:

> ולקחתם לכם ביום הראשון זה שאמר הכתוב אז ירננו כל עצי יער לפני ה' כי בא
>   כי בא לשפוט הארץ במי הכתוב מדבר בישראל ובאומות העולם שהקדוש ברוך הוא
>   דן אותן ביום הכפורים אלו ואלו נכנסין לפני המלך ואין אנו יודעין מי היה
>   מנצח משל למה הדבר דומה לשני בני אדם שנכנסו לדין לפני המלך ולא היה יודע
>   אדם מה ביניהם אלא המלך בלבד דן המלך אותן ולא היו יודעין הבריות מי נוצח
>   לחברו אמר המלך כל מי שהוא יוצא ובידו אגין הוו יודעין שהוא נצח כך ישראל
>   ואומות העולם נכנסין לדין [בראש השנה] וביום הכפורים ואין הבריות יודעין
>   מי נצח אמר הקדוש ברוך הוא טלו לולביכם בידכם שידעו הכל שאתם זכיתם בדין
>   לפיכך אמר דוד אז ירננו כל עצי יער לפני ה' אימתי כי בא כי בא לשפוט הארץ
>   [בראש השנה] וביום הכפורים (מה ישראל עושין ממתינים עוד חמשה ימים כדי
>   שידעו הכל שישראל זכו) לפיכך כתיב ולקחתם לכם ביום הראשון
>
> "And you shall take for yourself on the first day." This is what the
>   verse says, "then all  the trees of the forest shall sing before
>   Hashem, because he comes, he comes to judge the land." About whom is
>   the verse speaking? About Israel and the nations of the world. For
>   The-Holy-One-Blessed-Be-He judges them on Yom Kippur. These and these
>   enter before the king, and we don't know who is victorious. A parable,
>   to what is this compared? To two people who enter for judgement before
>   the king, and no man knows what is between them except for the king
>   alone. The king judges them and the creatures don't know who was
>   victorious over his friend. The king says, "whoever goes out with the branch/javelin in
>   his hand, you know that he was victorious. So, too, Israel and the
>   nations of the world enter for judgement [on Rosh Hashana and] on Yom
>   Kippur, and the creatures do not know who was victorious.
>   The-Holy-One-Blessed-Be-He says take your lulavs in your hands so that
>   everyone will know that you have triumphed in judgment. Therefore,
>   David said, "then all the trees of the forest will sing before
>   Hashem". When? "When he comes, when he comes to judge the land" on
>   [Rosh Hashana and] on Yom Kippur. (What does Israel do? They wait
>   another five days so that everyone should know that Israel triumphed.)
>   Therefore it is written, "And you shall take for yourself on the first
>   day."

While this Midrash does not specifically mention the waving, it is cited by various authorities (in slightly modified form) as the source-reason for the waving. It is first cited, I believe, by [R. Asher Ben Yechiel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asher_ben_Jehiel) and [R. David Abudraham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Abudirham), and later accepted as the reason by [R. Joseph Karo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Karo). They interpret the singing of the trees as referring to the waving of the Lulav.

**Rosh, Succah 3:26**

> ואיתא במדרש לפי שבר"ה באין לדין ישראל ואומות העולם ואין יודעין מי יצא
>   זכאי ומי יצא חייב נתן הקב"ה מצוה זו לישראל שיהו שמחים בלולביהם כאדם
>   היוצא מלפני השופט זכאי שהוא שמח והיינו דכתיב ירננו עצי היער כלומר
>   ירננו בעצי היער כאשר יצאו מלפני ה' זכאין כשבאין לשפוט את הארץ ובמה
>   ירננו בהודו ובהושיעה נא

**Abudraham, Seder Tefillat Succot**

> ואיתא במדרש לפי שבר"ה באין לדון ישראל ואומות העולם ואין יודעין מי יצא
>   זכאי מי יצא חייב נתן הקב"ה מצוה זו לישראל שיהיו שמחים בלולביהם כאדם
>   היוצא מלפני השופט זכאי שהוא שמח וזהו שכתוב ירננו עצי היער כלומר בעצי
>   יער כאשר יצאו מלפני ה' זכאין כשבא לשפוט את הארץ ובמה ירננו בהודו
>   והושיעא נא

**[Beit Yosef O.C. 641](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2775)**

> ואיתא במדרש לפי שבראש השנה באין לדין ישראל ואומות העולם ואין יודעין מי
>   יצא זכאי ומי יצא חייב נתן הקדוש ברוך הוא מצוה זו לישראל שיהיו שמחים
>   בלולביהם כאדם היוצא מלפני השופט זכאי שהוא שמח והיינו דכתיב ירננו עצי
>   היער כלומר ירננו בעצי היער כאשר יצאו מלפני יי' זכאין כשבא לשפוט את
>   הארץ ובמה ירננו בהודו ובהושיעה נא